# Walls like in Labyrinth game

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, intersection

I have two images: a marble and an obstacle.
I want to make sure the marble cant roll over the obstacle.
If the marble touches an edge of the obstacle it should be set to the previous coordinates so it would look like the marble stops on the edge of the obstacle.
What's the code for that?
My code:

```
CGRect obstacleBounceFrame = [_obstacleBounce frame];
CGRect intersectionWithObstacleBounce = CGRectIntersection(marbleFrame, obstacleBounceFrame);
if(CGRectIsNull(intersectionWithObstacleBounce)) {
    // Not touching yet - null intersection
} else {


}
```

Could someone give me the theory to do this?

Thanks Matis

[image]

Comment: If you want to look ahead to iOS 7 development, you could use the SpriteKit framework to take advantage of the new physics package. But, will only work for iOS 7+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the previous position of the marble like this:

```
CGRect previousPosition = marbleFrame.frame;
```

And in the next iteration, if the marble collides the wall, set its frame to that.

Other solution would be checking from which side is colliding (top, left, right or down), that's easy comparing the intersection rect (for example, if the intersection rect top side is bigger than his right side, it means that is colliding from top or down) and place the marbleFrame besides it, just before entering.

Or, you can just the awesome SpriteKit in iOS7 where it's really easy to do, but only for iOS7 devices.

Comment: Thx for your answer this helped me! I know the SpriteKit would be much easier but then I have to wait until IOS 7 is released to upload my program and that is no option. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, collision detection is not a easy thing to get working correctly, so you may want to look into some external libraries, such as ObjectiveChipmunk or Box2d.

That being said, there are a few things you could put into that else statement. The general way to go about it would be to "move the object back" so to speak, depending on which boundary he is hitting. If he is colliding with the left boundary, move him x units to the right, if he is hitting the top boundary, move him x units down, etc.

Another possible solution would be to keep track of the objects "valid" positions, and once it collides with a wall, return the object to its previous position.

Comment: It is very frustrating that I only can vote up when I have 15 xp could you please rate up my post so I can rate up your answer? =D